# What's the generator of spinor field shifts?

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, differentiation, spinors, calculus

The shift of a scalar field $\Phi$:
$$ \Phi \rightarrow \Phi'=\Phi - i \epsilon $$
is generated by 
$$ G = -i \frac{d}{d\Phi},$$
because
$$ \mathrm{e}^{-i \epsilon \frac{d}{d\Phi} } \Phi = (1-i\epsilon \frac{d}{d\Phi} + \ldots ) \Phi \approx \Phi - i \epsilon .$$

What is the analogous generator for shifts of a Weyl spinor field $\Psi$
$$ \Psi \rightarrow \Psi'=\Psi - i \xi \quad ? $$
In index notation, we have
$$  \Psi_\alpha \rightarrow \Psi_\alpha'=\Psi_\alpha - i \xi_\alpha  .$$
Naively, one gets
$$ G_\beta = -i \frac{d}{d\Psi_\beta},$$
$$ \mathrm{e}^{-i \xi_\beta \frac{d}{d\Psi_\beta} } \Psi_\alpha = (1-i\xi_\beta \frac{d}{d\Psi_\beta} + \ldots ) \Psi_\alpha \approx \Psi_\alpha  - i \xi_\alpha  .$$

where I used $\frac{d}{d\Psi_\beta} \Psi_\alpha = \delta_{\alpha \beta} $.

I'm really unsure about the spinor indices here. Shouldn't there be a spinor metric $i \sigma_2$ somewhere, because we are multiplying spinors? Does $\frac{d}{d\Psi_\beta} \Psi_\alpha = \delta_{\alpha \beta} $ make sense at all?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial\Psi_\beta}\Psi_\alpha=\delta^\beta_\alpha$ is a well-defined result of the basic algebra of spinors (but note the position of indices).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in my comment above,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\Psi_\beta}\Psi_\alpha=\delta^\beta_\alpha
$$
is one of the basic results of the algebra of spinors (but notice that the index $\beta$ is an *upper index*).

The generator
$$
G_\beta = -i \frac{d}{d\Psi_\beta},
$$
is used, for example, to define supercovariant derivatives (e.g., see [Superspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superspace), where you can find $D=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}+\cdots$).